# how to read object from one position of an ArrayList to the same position in another ArrayList

Tags: java, collections, arraylist

how to read an object from position y of one ArrayList to the same position y of another Arraylist? what is the best way to do this?

i have some code below that shows what i am trying to do.  this code does not work but it gives the general idea of what i am trying to do.

Looking for an alternative way to do this, or better way.

```
  ArrayList<Prize> xrt = new ArrayList<Prize>();
  ArrayList<Prize> rungame = new ArrayList<Prize>();

  for(int y = 0; y < xrt.size(); y++){

  rungame.set(y, xrt.get(y));

  }
```

Comment: Your code seems to aim to copy the whole ArrayList, that is easier done by this code: ArrayList<Prize> rungame= new ArrayList<Prize>(xrt);  -- If you just want to copy some individual objects your code (except for the loop) is fine.

Comment: This looks like a database struture in my point of view. A foreign key and a primary key. But anyway, @Thommy comment should give you a starting point.

Comment: yes, i am working on a database

Comment: Why do you deal with the `ArrayList` then? Can't you just create simple classes and extract the objects from the database by a sql query. Just curious.

Comment: i am using sql query to get the objects but i got to put them in an array or arrayList because i have to put different numbers of them in the arrayList.  example  A(6)  B(1) C(5) D(2)  and display like this,  AAAAAABCCCCCDD   so position one is "A" and if you go to position 7 you would get "B"

Comment: the object has 2 fields, String name, and Integer hits.   hits is the number of times the object will show up in the array or ArrayList.  for the above example.  hits for A is 6, so A will show up in 6 positions inside the ArrayList

Comment: Use a HasMap instead , with key being name and value is count.

Comment: i think i need an array or arrayList becasause i need to pick a random number and if "A" is represented in the array 6 times, it has more chance to be chosen than "D" which only has 2 positions in the array.  more positions taken up gets it more chances to be picked.  so i got to put all of them in the array or ArrayList linerally and pick an index by random roll of the dice. do decide the winner

Comment: One thought would be to transform the arraylists into arrays.

Comment: that is a good idea,  but i thought it is easier to work with collections like ArrayList.   however the array could be better for this situation

Answer (score 1):

For index to index copy : [`Collections.copy(List dest, List src)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#copy%28java.util.List,%20java.util.List%29)